# Merge DataFrames on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames

df1 consists of columns: `person_id,day,flag`

df2 consists of columns: `person_id,day_start,day_end`

I want to add to df2 column `num_flags` which will show sum of `flag` column within `person_id` and `day_start < day < day_end` interval.

Which is the fastest way to do this without complicated loops? I'm seeking for fast solution like `merge`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on="person_id", how="outer")
>>> df["lies_between"] = df.day.between(df.day_start, df.day_end,inclusive=False)
>>> x = pd.pivot_table(df,values="flags",columns="lies_between", index="person_id",aggfunc=np.sum)
>>> x.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)
>>> x[["person_id", True]]
```

This can be helpful:

```
>>> help(pandas.Series.between_time)
```